# Bootstrap DropdownButton Styling

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
header_contents.push(<DropdownButton bsSize='xsmall' bsStyle='link' pullRight={true} id={1} title='Menu'>
    {item_menu}
  </DropdownButton>);
```

I want to have the styling in Bootstrap to be white lettering (currently blue) as I think the link option is defaulted to that. How can you change the styling for Bootstrap to pass link color, and other properties like if you want to move the link down a little on the page?

I should mention we do very little CSS styling as most of that is done within the ReactJS components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of an online chat room. Here's what I did.

I first made a style (dropDownLinkStyle) in the react component like this.

```
let dropDownLinkStyle = {
  color: 'white'
};
```

Then I used it (dropDownLinkStyle) in the dropdownButton like this.

```
header_contents.push(<DropdownButton bsSize='large' style={dropDownLinkStyle} bsStyle='link' pullRight={true} id={1 /* avoids react warning */} title='Menu'>
    {item_menu}
  </DropdownButton>);
```

I hope this helps. This allowed me to keep my bsStyle which is link (tells Bootstrap I want a link type on my screen instead of a button) and allows me to change that link to white lettering. I could also pass more styling by just adding it to the object -- dropDownLinkStyle

Answer (score 0):

Either override bootstrap CSS in a css file (that is what your seem to avoid I understand): it is the better way to ensure a global effect over every link in your application.

Or do no sent `bsStyle='link'` as `DropdownButton` property but instead, insert a `style` property with custom CSS. Yet you can insert `style` even if you don't remove `bsStyle`. You could then create your own component wrapping `DropdownButton` to ensure the same graphic chart in your application.